# Firebird: Why won't this sql statement find record when it exists?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT * from tBooks where BookNbr = '20111122-001'
```

BookNbr is defined as `varchar (15)`, and the record does exist in the table.

I think it might have something to do with the dash, but don't know why...

Comment: Maybe you have some spaces in your data. try `where BookNbr like '20111122-001%'`

Comment: What happens if you do a like, such as SELECT * from tBooks where BookNbr like '20111122-001%'?  Have you looked for trailing spaces?

Comment: @juergend- You beat me too it.

Comment: Maybe the quotes are missing?  It would then look like an arithmetic expression for 20111121.

Comment: No, quotes are not missing (I'm using SQLMaestro (Firebird edition)

Comment: (spokane-dude:  use @username so we get a notification that you have replied.)  How do you *know* the record exists?  (Especially since a query for it does not find it.)

Comment: wallyk:  @username gives me an error
I can see the record  using SQLMaestro (Firebird edition)

Comment: It's the dash... I removed it in the record, and FB found the modified record.  So, how do I fix my select statement so it finds records no matter what's in the search pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it is probably a hyphen vs. en dash vs. em dash issue.  (You can confirm this by pasting the displayed matching field into an ascii editor to see if a multi-byte character appears.)

```
SELECT * from tBooks where BookNbr like '20111122%001'
```

so that `%` ignores the specific punctuation in the midst.

Comment: And underscore would be better if you know it's just one character.

Comment: @Jesse:  that might cause the same problem if the field is not unicode.

Comment: Do you suppose it's taking the dash as part of a "regular expression" in the where clause?

Comment: @wallyk, I don't follow, % is wildcard for any number of characters, _ for just one character.  You're saying there is issues with using the _ wildcard in non-unicode?

Comment: @spokane-dude:  No, it isn't.  The `LIKE` operator in the expression causes pattern matching.

Comment: @Jesse:  The evidence suggests that it is not a hyphen in the database and the schema is not known to us.  To get a speedy resolution, a `%` is a surer kill.  A `_` might prolong the suffering.

Comment: @wallyk, I know but it is most likely a single character so the _ would be the best wildcard to use.  Otherwise other matches might be present ie '20111122-1001' or '20111122DONALDTRUMP001'

Comment: @wallyk, ahhh, I get what you're saying, as a troubleshooting method it's more inclusive and therefore better.  Good call.

Comment: @Jesse:  True, but I leave it for the OP to consider the merits.  Most ISBNs are better behaved than that.

Comment: So what are you guys suggesting?  btw, it's not an ISBN, it's the user defined key to the table.

Comment: @spokane-dude:  Change the query so it is not a hard match for a particular value, but a `LIKE` expression where the hyphen or dash is omitted.

Comment: @wallyk I don't think that is going to work... this user may or may not have a dash in that particular position of the field...

Comment: @spokane-dude:  this is not intended to be a permanent solution.  Probably just a workaround until the database can be normalized to always use hyphens or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solution provided by @wallyk, the problem could also be caused by a corrupted index entry. You can check this by bypassing the index using

```
SELECT * from tBooks where BookNbr||'' = '20111122-001'
```

If this does return the record, then it would be wise to backup and restore the database to rebuild the index (or to drop and recreate the index).